# Will renaming Visio's `ThisDocument` module cause any problems?

Tags: vba, visio, vbide

The default Viso document has a CodeName of `ThisDocument` and unlike other Office documents, the `ThisDocument` component's `CodeName` appears to be Read Only.

If I have trusted access to the VBE, then I *can* rename the component, with a line like this:

```
ThisDocument.vbProject.vbComponents("ThisDocument").Name = "FooBar"
```

And from that point on, I can refer to the object as `FooBar` instead of `ThisDocument`

But, presumably, the CodeName is Read-Only for a reason. I can't find any issues with renaming the object, *so far*, but I'm unsure if there might be some unexpected ramifications.

Is it safe/wise to rename the `ThisDocument` component?

Comment: The first thing I'd worry about is Events - maybe do a before/after test to see if they're still hooked up correctly.

Comment: @Mat'sMug this (see my answer) is also a problem in MS Word - stumbled upon this while using the awesomeness of Rubberduck *(which probably shouldn't have allowed me to rename ThisDocument to SomeThing)*.  Most things seemed to work (in MS Word), except for macro buttons

Answer (score 2):

When the double click event of a shape is linked to a macro (as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/associate-macros-or-add-ons-with-the-double-click-behavior-of-shapes), to create a Macrobutton of sorts) things break. Tested with Visio 2010 - 64bit version.

Furthermore after reinstating the original name of ThisDocument...

- FooBar.vbProject.vbComponents("FooBar").Name = "ThisDocument"

... everything worked again :)

[image: linking shapes to macro]

Comment: This is also an issue in MS Word, however in MS Word other events still seem to work. Code for MacroButtons was simply not found *(although there might be a way)*.

Comment: I can rename a word document component, but the "Sub or Function not defined" error appears until.. it doesn't, but I don't know what triggers (and can't reliably reproduce the steps) the field to refresh. In any event, a MacroButton macro shouldn't be in the document module, it should be in a standard module. With that approach, renaming the module still allows the MacroButton to find the procedure. While Visio does allow a shape's DblClick to refer to a procedure in a std module, the shape persists a module-qualified reference to the procedure, so any rename would need to update the shape.

Comment: @ThunderFrame so... the error disappears?! That's fun :-D  WRT my testing in MS Word, indeed the Macrobutton Code was in a standard module.  I just showed the MB code in "ThisDocument" for visio because it was less work ;-)

Comment: @ThunderFrame also, not sure if you checked in Word, but you can just type over ThisDocument in the properties window. So even though it's not read only, it still breaks :(

Comment: I was able to get all of the MACROBUTTON fields in Word to work again by executing `On Error Resume Next : Application.Run vbNullString`. Obvious, huh?!?!?! %^)

Comment: And recording a macro in Visio 2010, shows me that I can reassign the macro `Application.Windows.ItemEx("Drawing1:Page-1:Decision <SHAPE>").Activate` and then `Application.ActiveWindow.Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowEvent, visEvtCellDblClick).FormulaU = "RUNMACRO(""newDocName.aaaa"")"`

Comment: I'm not even going to ask how long it took you to figure out the `OERN : Application.Run vbNullstring` - it's mind blowing that you even tried it; possessed much!?